# How to convert ndarray into IMAGE type

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

load_image function doesn't accept ndarray Type. The function only accept IMAGE type.

Is it possible to convert ndarray type into IMAGE type or _ImageCrop type into IMAGE type?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code - it is very hard to run them! Instead, click `edit` under your image and paste a complete, minimal example that is complete and runnable and shows what the problem is.

Comment: As I mentioned above, load_image function only accepts IMAGE type. I just wanna know to convert "ndarray Type" into "IMAGE type". So, I think this picture is proper.  You don't need to run above code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of the problem, you want to convert numpy array into image format (PIL). This can be done by following code:

```
import numpy
import PIL

#Convert nparray to PIL image
img = PIL.Image.fromarray(arr)    #arr is numpy array
```

Comment: When I add "im2 = Image.fromarray(crop_area)" code to above code, I got an error "ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image".

Comment: I solved the error, but compiler said "image Instance is not IMAGE Instance (meaning image Instance is different from IMAGE Instance).

Comment: Try using PIL.Image.fromarray() and not just Image.fromarray()

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# monochrome:
X1 = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(256,256), dtype=np.uint8)
image1 = Image.fromarray(X1, "L")
image1.show()

# color:
X2 = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(256,256,3), dtype=np.uint8)
image2 = Image.fromarray(X2, "RGB")
image2.show()
```

Check out different modes:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: compiler said, "image Instance is not IMAGE Instance (meaning image Instance is different from IMAGE Instance)".

Comment: Try `type(image)` to get the type of `image` variable and understand with which object you are dealing with.